# How to return value from azure async function v2?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime, azure-function-async

I am writing javascript first time. 
within the azure function app I have one async function to insert data using query see function code as below

```
async function insertData(query) {

var connection = new Connection(config);
var result = 'Connecting'

await connection.on('connect', function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Connect: ' + err);
        result = 'Connect: ' + err;
    } else {
        request = new Request(query + "; select @@identity", function (err, rowCount) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('Insert: ' + err);
                result = 'Insert: ' + err;
            } else {
                console.log('Insert complete.');
                result = 'Insert complete';
            }
            connection.close();
        });
        connection.execSql(request);
    }
});
return result;
};
```

and I am calling this fuction from main triggerd function like this

```
   var result = insertData(query);  // calling function from here
   context.log('Result ' + result); // Result [object Promise]
```

but it is not giving proper value of `result` at log it is `Result [object Promise]` it should be `Insert complete` as it inserted recorted successfuly
can you please currect me? Thanks!

Comment: Javascript actually works in asynchronous way, it will send a request and returns a promise. It will then automatically move to your next code to execute. To resolve this you need to use the promise with then. use the following code result.then(function(result){ //Your Success code }, function(error) {alert("error"});